# Ubuntu 13.10 gets stuck on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.10

I have updated (via the Software Updater) Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10. 
After it had finished the installation, the system required a reboot.
When I reboot and load Ubuntu it will get stuck on the logo. I managed to boot into the recovery (both console and graphics mode) but I can't figure out how to repair it.

I have tried a sudo update-grub, but nothing different happened. I have also tried sudo apt-get install gnome, but the same result...

I am using a dual-boot Win7 + Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem, it seems it's a bug in Ubuntu 13.10. I recommend you trying these:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdm gnome-panel
```

also try "chkdsk /f" from windows.

if it doesn't work reinstall Ubuntu 13.10
it mostly happens when u boot into windows.

Comment: Please do not change the entire context of your answer - If you have a completely different approach make a new answer.

Comment: sorry posting new one i thought telling in comment but i will just make new one:)